# Is an arrow function more performant than a similar regular (anonymous) function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords.

Presumably, not binding is more performant than binding.

Comment: Why “surely” (or “presumably”)? This seems to be asking for a list of reasons to explain a benchmark, except the benchmark doesn’t exist.

Comment: Presumably, doing nothing is quicker than doing something.

Comment: The quote is a description of differences in how the types of functions behave, it’s not that a non-arrow function is required to be implemented as an arrow function plus several steps of overhead to bind stuff. If you don’t use any of those things in a function, there’s no need for the engine to distinguish arrow functions from non-arrow functions except in how they’re allowed to be called.

Comment: I never thought a non-arrow function is required to be implemented as an arrow function.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036554/performance-regular-vs-arrow-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My presumption is unfounded.  Based on the following timings, creating an arrow function is *not* more performant than creating a regular anonymous function.

**Regular Anonymous Function**

```
let f;
for (let I = 0; I < 10; ++I) {
    console.time();
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) f = function (x) {return x;};
    console.timeEnd();
}
```

```
[Debug] default: 14665.279ms
[Debug] default: 14716.809ms
[Debug] default: 14640.227ms
[Debug] default: 14786.576ms
[Debug] default: 14748.089ms
[Debug] default: 14785.006ms
[Debug] default: 14795.267ms
[Debug] default: 14861.353ms
[Debug] default: 14878.316ms
[Debug] default: 14955.095ms
```

mean = 14783.202 ± 30.705 ms

**Arrow Function**

```
let f;
for (let I = 0; I < 10; ++I) {
    console.time();
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) f = (x) => {return x;};
    console.timeEnd();
}
```

```
[Debug] default: 14683.146ms
[Debug] default: 14772.154ms
[Debug] default: 14756.878ms
[Debug] default: 14667.755ms
[Debug] default: 14729.087ms
[Debug] default: 14770.861ms
[Debug] default: 14808.871ms
[Debug] default: 14865.292ms
[Debug] default: 14901.789ms
[Debug] default: 14928.623ms
```

mean = 14788.446 ± 27.802 ms

Answer (score 2):

> How is an arrow function more performant than a similar regular (anonymous) function?

[It isn't](https://jsben.ch/atQIj). Both are `function` type, and the performance difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

It's more performant if you are in a situation where you need to reference `this` and the arrow function exposes the `this` from the outer scope, so that you don't need to do the `let that = this;` shenanigan:

```js
let obj = {
  count: 1,

  doSomething: function() {
    this.count++
  },

  faster: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.doSomething();
    }, 1000);
  },

  slower: function() {
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.doSomething();
    }, 1000);
  },
};
```