# What is another compelling use case for arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Unexpectedly (to me), [an arrow function is *not* more performant than a similar regular (anonymous) function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62724362/13744178) with respect to both [creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62747733/13744178) and [execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724473/13744178).  Except for concision and avoiding [a use case for "`that`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725016/13744178) (See also [No separate `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description).), is there a compelling use case for arrow functions?

Comment: By what criteria do you define "compelling" to be, that others would not take as "opinionated"?

Comment: Arrow functions were not meant as a performance enhancer.  They were meant to fix common scoping issues.

Comment: `Except for concision and avoiding a use case for "that" (See also No separate this.)` That's it; that's the reason. So if those features make it the right tool for whatever job you're trying to do, use it. If a different tool is appropriate, use that.

Comment: Thanks, @NicholasTower!

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions are shorter, and make your code easier to read / debug. They tell what needs to be done (functional programming paradigm), and not how it needs to be done (object oriented programming paradigm).

However, they are not a good choice for object methods (to do with the "this", and binding) and with dynamic event listeners.

To understand what I said in greater detail, consult this article: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/